# Copy a file structure THEN rename a subfolder in the same command line

Tags: cmd

I have a conditional statement that is passed to CMD that is intended automate a process. The part that isn't working is intended to copy a file structure and then rename a sub folder in the copy.

Presently it only executes the first statement and reports no errors. During testing, the statements execute independently of each other, ( suggesting some sort of locking ?)

The complete (shortened) statement is as follows:

> robocopy "C:\Users...__templateShoot" "C:\Users...test" *.* /E && ren
>   "C:\Users...test\__Unscheduled" "aDate"

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this syntax:

```
robocopy "C:\Users...__templateShoot" "C:\Users...test" /E &
    rename "C:\Users...test\__Unscheduled" "aDate"
```

You had two `&&` instead of one, and you had an extraneous period `.` before the `/E` flag for `robocopy`.

From the [documentation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy):

> Robocopy syntax is markedly different from standard copy commands, as it accepts only folder names as its source and destination arguments. File names and wild-card characters (such as "*.*") are not valid source or destination arguments.

The `/E` switch already instructs Robocopy to copy everything recursively.

Comment: Sorry the additional dot isn't. It is a formatting error on my part as it should be \*.\*

Comment: In addition to the extra '&', I needed to place 'cmd /C ' at the front of each command - and the copy is working (even if it shouldn't be). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you doing this from Java?  You should have labelled your question as such.

Comment: No - from a FM runtime